# How to move around items in QtDesigner?

Tags: python, qt

I have a very silly problem.[image]

I would like to move the top layout on the right side of my MainWindow down ( I mean under the layouts with the push buttons). Well, in Android Studio in such case I would simply move desired components inside my object inspector and arrange the order there. However in Qt Desing it is "frozen" and I'm not able to do it.

What is the simpliest way to move the components around in the desired hierarchy?

Comment: Do you get a warrning/error when you drag/drop it to the desired location?

Comment: I simply cant do it. There is no reaction on my clicks in the object inspector. I can move the stuff around in the main window, but it's not very comfortable, sometimes even impossible (like in the picture attached).

Comment: Should be moved to StackExchange while this is no specific programming problem.

Comment: No it should not @linusg. Meta Stack Exchange is for the questions regarding the Stack Exchange network itself. This question is on topic here.

Comment: have you tried editing the layout positions to see if they move?

Comment: @Andy Not Meta. Sorry, I meant Superuser...

Comment: Have you tried breaking the layouts? Right click, Layout, Break layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not move widgets/layouts from the object inspector, the items are just displayed in alphabetical order. You have to do it on the graphical elements.

You should be able to drag&drop your layout and see a blue line where it is going to be *inserted*. When you have a main layout, it fills all the space available so you can only insert widgets/other-layouts between other elements.

The easiest way from scratch is to place all the widgets (and spacers) you need, without taking care of sizes and alignment, then wrap them into layouts from the most inner layout to the most outer.